# Run code when TabView gesture begins and ends

Tags: swift, swiftui, gesture

I have a SwiftUI TabView, and I'm trying to run code when the TabView drag gesture begins, and when it ends.

In this code, "Drag gesture begins" prints, but "Drag gesture ends" does not. I tried with gesture(), simultaneousGesture(), but neither work. Any ideas?

```swift
TabView {
    ForEach(0..<5) { index in
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            // content
        }
    }
}
.ignoresSafeArea()
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
.indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
.simultaneousGesture(
    DragGesture()
        .onChanged { gesture in
            print("Drag gesture begins")
        }
        .onEnded { gesture in
            print("Drag gesture ends")
        }
)
```

Comment: It is printed. But only if move your gesture from up to down of screen or vice versa (vertically, or from one edge to another). For horizontally it is works unpredictable, because you changed page

Comment: @Arsienij oh yes, interesting. I hadn't noticed it works vertically. So is there no way I can do it horizontally?

Comment: I think no, because it is conflicted with TabView. Do you want react when new page is swiped? I think you can place that gesture at ForEach and interact with content directly, that will works

Comment: You can always put a GeometryReader in the view, and watch for the change there. You can then run your code from that. But no, you can't have a gesture on a paged tabview.